# How to add a loader to a page till I get the data in the background from API in xamarin android MVVM/mono

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am able to get the data from the API which I am using it to bind the data in different ways but when getting the data is going slow, black screen is displayed for some time and then the data is getting loaded so I was trying to rectify that and make the data getting in background(async await) and then bind that to the view when the data is available locally.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Well basic idea is to use `ActivityIndicator` view which basically is a loading control in each platform. How you use it thought is different in different cases. I personally wrap content of the page in a grid like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns:a="">
    <Grid>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
        <[The original page content]>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Then you create a Boolean property named `IsBusy` in your view model and set it to true when loading content and false after you are done.

**-- Edit --**

Sorry I didn't notice the original question was about Android and not forms. I will let the previous answer remain here in case anyone wanted to know about Forms solution.

So in Android the quivalant is `ProgressDialog`. I know you can use it like this:

```
ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
```

You put this code after starting you web call in *another thread*.

There might be better ways so search for the `ProgressDialog` and you will find them.

Comment: I think it is for Xamarin Forms, but I require it in Xamarin Android Native. I tried to implement it in that any way but I failed to implement that. Can you please help me to do that in the native

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't paying enough attention to your question. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ProgressDialog` with `MvvmCross` (I see that tag under the topic) you may read an [article](http://slodge.blogspot.ru/2013/07/n34-showing-progress-isbusy-display-n1.html) by Stuart

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sample layout skeleton for those screens where you need to show the activity indicator (Loader):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Text 1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Text 2"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/loader"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Accordingly you need to control the `FrameLayout` from it's id containing the progress bar from your code end either in activity or if you are using fragment to make it visible during the service call and set the visibility to invisible once you received the response.